# how to transfer token with timestamp to restrict token transfer

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-20

I am working on basic ERC20 token smart contract and i would like to add some conditions in token transfer

Suppose, I transfer 100 tokens to  receiver on 2018-03-01 then receiver can't sent that 100 tokens before 2018-03-15 and If i transfer another 100 tokens to same receiver on 2018-03-05 then another 100 tokens can't be sent before 2018-03-20

What would be the code for that scenario, Thanks.

Comment: It is cleaner not to modify the token contract itself, but create a separate time locked token vault contract. Here is an example: https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/TokenVault.sol

Comment: I have seen your code but its not actually what i am looking for. I need to associate a timestamp with tokens on every transfer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but not the most efficient way, might be to just keep a mapping of each transfers value and timestamp and loop through that to see what balance should still be held based off the timestamp.

Once you get that balance, one of your `require`s in your internal transfer method would change from `require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value)` to `require(balanceOf[_from] - timeLockedBalance >= _value)`

The problem with this method though is dealing with this on exchanges. With the timelock, your token literally becomes untradable.